# Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-a_n)^k}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n\to \lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{a_n}{n}\to 0$ and let $k\in \mathbb{N_0}$.

I have to prove that $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-a_n)^k}=1$$

---

I tried this:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-a_n)^k}=\frac{n!}{\sum_{i=0}^{k}(n-k)!\binom{k}{i}n^ia_n^{k-i}}=\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{n^ia_n^{k-i}}{i!(k-i)!}}$$

But it doesn't help much. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$S_n=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(n-a_n)^k}$$ Take logarithms
$$\log(S_n)=\log(n!)-\log((n-k)!)-k\Big[\log(n)+\log \left(1-\frac{a_n}{n}\right)\Big]$$ Using Stirling approximation twice and continuing with Taylor expansions
$$\log(S_n)=\frac{k (2 a_n-k+1)}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ So, $\log(S_n)\to 0$ and then $S_n \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for large enough $n$, your sequence is $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}{\frac{1-i/n}{1-a_n/n}}$.